# Shell script to display files system which uses more than 5% disk storage

Tags: shell-script

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How the grep command works in this script? I have this many file systems (refer image) and I want to execute the script in such a way that it works based on alert condition based on the filesystems][1]][1]

This was my script

```
ALERT=5 
df -h | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 , $1 }' > sample.txt 
while read line; do 
  var1=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d '%' -f1 ) 
  echo $var1 
  var2=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }' ) 
  echo $var2 
  if [ "$var1" > $ALERT ]; then 
     echo "Alert: Almost out of disk space" 
  fi 
done < sample.txt
```

I want to display file systems which uses more than 5% disk usage but i am getting file systems with 4% disk usage after executing the script.

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted 
on overlay 880G 28G 808G 4% / 
tmpfs 126G 0 126G 0% /dev 
tmpfs 126G 0 126G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
/dev/sdb1 880G 28G 808G 4% /etc/hosts 
shm 64M 996K 64M 2% /dev/shm 
/dev/sda3 215G 21G 183G 10% /home/cg/root 
tmpfs 126G 0 126G 0% /proc/scsi 
tmpfs 126G 0 126G 0% /sys/firmware 
4 overlay   
Alert: Almost out of disk space 4 /dev/sdb1 Alert: Almost out of disk space 2 shm 
Alert: Almost out of disk space 10 /dev/sda3 Alert: Almost out of disk space
```

Comment: Please put your script as text into the question, not as a screenshot. Also, you might want to remove your mail address.

Comment: **You are reinventing monitoring tools, and doing it badly.**  I recommend looking into modern monitoring solutions, e.g. netdata, which you might combine with Prometheus and grafana if you have many hosts to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

- You seem to be looking only to measure local file
  systems, in that case use `-l` with `df`
- For skipping the df header, a simple `sed 1d` would suffice
- Use printf in awk for output formatting
- awk can handle string to number conversion by itself. Say, if the fifth column is a number with percentage sign , `$5+0` will convert it to a number only

With these your clean script would be

```
df -lh | sed 1d | awk '{ if( $5+0  >5) printf "ALERT FOR %s at %d%%\n",$1, $5}'
```